# Why does this function not work properly in an "if" statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I think the reason is probably I did not close the scanner of "tf4". If I close it, then complie it, everything is ok but when I the system sends "error":  the system will say:Exception 
in thread "main" java.lang.illegalstateexception scanner closed.

The code used to generate tf4:

```
public static String[] txtDocument(String args1) throws Exception{
    Scanner scannerTXT = new Scanner(new File(file1));
    String[] list4 = new String[2];

    int count3=0;
    while (scannerTXT.hasNextLine()) {
        String data = scannerTXT.nextLine();
     if(data.contains(args1)){
             count3++;
        String list1 = data;
        for(int i_t1=0;i_t1<2;i_t1++){  
            list4 = list1.split(",");
        break;
        }
          }

    if(count3==0){

            list4[0]="";  
            list4[1]="";   
    }
    scannerTXT.close();

        }

    return list4; 

    }
```

"tf4" is the made by this method. The architecture of the codes which generates "tf5" is similar but the code cannot run with this command( scannerTXT.close();).

I think this should be the main point. Because when the removeLineFromFile method works well when leaving the if statement.

---

1) If I put it here, it works very well:

Part of the structure is:

```
public class cs1{
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{

         cs1 k = new cs1();
        ***k.removeLineFromFile(file1,args[0]);***   


      if(tf4[1].length()!=0){  
               if(!tf4[1].trim().equals(tf5[3].trim())){  
                ...............
```

2) But if I put it in the if-else condition, it always return: "Could not delete file"

```
public class cs1{
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{


         cs1 k = new cs1();


      if(tf4[1].length()!=0){  
               if(!tf4[1].trim().equals(tf5[3].trim())){  
                  ***k.removeLineFromFile(file1,args[0]);*** 
                ...............
```

Could anyone tell me why? This is so odd.

Comment: Have you debugged this piece of code before posting it here trying to get an answer?

Comment: No way for us to help.  for starters, we now nothing about tf4 and so can't even hazard a guess to your problem(s)

Comment: Could it be that TestMain is operating on the same file so the file gets locked by `new TestMain` ?

Comment: Have you tried calling `k.removeLineFromFile()` just after `new Testmain()` ? Does it work in that case?

Comment: @nielsen Thank you very much for your reply. I tried to close the TestMain file but nothing gets better. The "Testmain tf3 = new Testmain();" is a mistake.Sorry for that, I have deleted it.    It looks I cannot directly call "k.removeLineFromFile()"...

Comment: @Delibz - I'll suggest you edit your question to show how the code looks now. Both for the good and the failing case. Perhaps you should also show the code for tf4 and tf5.

Comment: @nielsen Thank you for your patient very much, I have find sth which look wired. Sorry that the full piece of codes takes 600 lines...I cannot pull all of them here.

Comment: @nielsen sorry I did not get you. What does "close the file"mean? Close which file? The method "txtDocument" and the previous codes are in the same class, and i have closed all txt files...but problems are still there....

Comment: @Delibz - Forget that comment - I deleted the comment again as I reliazed it was wrong. However, looking at your scanner code it seems your are closing it inside the while-loop. Try moving the `scannerTXT.close();` down so that it is just before `return list4;`

Comment: @nielsen This annoying issue has gone...thank you so much for your patient man!

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
public static String[] txtDocument(String args1) throws Exception{
   Scanner scannerTXT = new Scanner(new File(file1));
   String[] list4 = new String[2];

    int count3=0;
    while (scannerTXT.hasNextLine()) {
        String data = scannerTXT.nextLine();
        if(data.contains(args1)){
            count3++;
            String list1 = data;
            for(int i_t1=0;i_t1<2;i_t1++){  
                list4 = list1.split(",");
                break;
            }
        }

        if(count3==0){
            list4[0]="";  
            list4[1]="";   
        }

        // Not here...   scannerTXT.close();
    }

    scannerTXT.close();  // But here
    return list4; 
}
```

Guess you'll get rid of the exception and further the file will be closed so that you can delete it later on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and patient. I really appreciate it. I created this class for test and I just copied the requested codes from other class files. I just renamed another file and finally......like what you said, I should close the file.

Comment: @Delibz - If this was the answer solving your problem, you should mark it as accepted so others can see that it helped.